# Call JS function after HTTP request is completed and rendered in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular8

I would like to call a function from external JS file to handle elements which are in a component (content coming from an HTTP request). The script is loading fine but way before the HTTP response so I cannot use my function. Here is my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from '../http.service'
import * as $ from 'jquery';
declare const myFunc: any;


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  items: object;

  constructor(private _http: HttpService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._http.myList().subscribe(
      data =>{
        this.items= data;
        console.log(this.items);
      },    
      myFunc(),
    )
  } 
}
```

Any idea how I can load my script after all the data of the component is loaded?

thanks!

Comment: That's what the `data => { this.items = data; console.log(this.items); }` function does: it is executed when the HTTP response arrives. If you want to execute something AFTER that you can use `setTimeout(function)` inside of it which will run immediatly after all synchronous code has executed. Also, don't rely on the execution of code on the import of a JavaScript script inside of an Angular project, that's really bad.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to call `myFunc()` inside of the body of the function above? Where you placed it now the return value of myFunc will be used as an error handler for the HTTP call, which most likely makes no sense.

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper, I tried the setTimeout  and it didnt work. What I want is just to be able to use my external JS  code when the view is loaded (with the retrieved data). 
I tried to add it as a tag in index.html and in the component html part without success.
Is this even possible?

Comment: You really shouldn't import self written Javascript code in Angular... There is 0 reason for it: Angular code itself is Javascript ... why not just write the code where it belongs like inside a .ts file (the typescript equivalent of a javascript file) and import a function that you can call?

Comment: Why not write the `myFunc` function you need inside of the  HomeComponent class and do `this.myFunc()` right under the `console.log`? Absolutely drop the idea of importing Javascript files.

Comment: Yes but will it work on html elements that are loaded after the script??  My problem is how can I add a function once the data is loaded. I think the solution could be in ngAfterViewCheck!

Comment: There is most likely also no reason for you to contact the HTML from your TS file using `ngAfterViewCheck`. Just set some variable on your component like `this.myVar = myFunc();` and then bind that in your HTML `<some-component [afterData]="myVar">`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, you should leverage `ngAfterViewInit`. This method is called once your view is initialized, and by this time data returned from api is used in html.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    items: object;

    constructor(private _http: HttpService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this._http.myList().subscribe(
        data => {
          this.items = data;
          console.log(this.items);
        }
      )
    }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
      myFunc();
    }
  }
```

Your current func call doesn't make sense as it will work as the error callback function of subscribe as pointed by @Robin.

[ngAfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit)

Comment: Thanks, I tried all the hooks, only the ones with on"Check" are coming after the array, all the rest are executed before.. so doesnt solve my problem unfortunately. excuse my ignorance but if it's global function is should work everywhere on the SPA including on data loaded later on... seems counter-intuitive!